# Mouse cursor invisible after installing Parallel Tools

Tags: mouse, virtualization

After installing Parallel tools, the mouse pointer is not visible but works if I click. Can I re-enable it via Terminal?

Comment: I faced this issue in Parallels when I installed ElementaryOS Loki. Let me know if you are doing installation on Parallels then I can help you. Most people complained about mouse not showing or working when installing on Parallels

Comment: Yes. The mouse disappears until the installation of parallel tools. :-/ Can I restore the original driver of elementary??

Answer (score 4):

So here is the solution if you are using Parallels to install ElementaryOS Loki

There is no Parallel Tools driver issue. It is just Boot Flag setting.

After installation of Parallel Tools, shut down and don't start Loki. Go to

**Settings --> Hardware --> Boot Order**

There you would see Advanced Settings, where you can set the boot flags. Type there

```
devices.usb.mouse=1
```

And now start your Virtual Machine, it would work

if `1` doesn't work then try `0`. But for me in Parallels, `1` worked

Comment: the `devices.usb.mouse=1` worked for me, a value of `0` did not.